# Pushforward of a derivation

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tangent-spaces, derivations

I am trying to compute the pushforward of a tangent vector as a derivation. Here are my definitions:

Let $v\in \left.(TM)\right|_U$ be a tangent vector at the point $p$. Given some coordinates $(\phi,U)$, this can be expressed as
\begin{align}
v=\sum_{i}a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^i}(p).
\end{align}

Define the pushforward of a vector under a map $\psi$ by its action on a function $f$:
\begin{align}
(\psi_*v)(f)=v(f\circ \psi).
\end{align}

What I want to calculate is the pushforward of $v$ under the chart $\phi$. As far as I can understand from reading, this should give me the vector $a$, but I'm struggling to get there. I think it is something to do with exactly how the standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are defined, as I'm not sure. Here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
(\phi_*v)(f)&=v(f\circ \phi)\\
&=\sum_{i}a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^i}(p)(f\circ \phi)\\
&=\sum_{i}a^i\frac{\partial (f\circ \phi)}{\partial \phi^i}(p)\\
&=\sum_{i}a^i D_i(f\circ \phi\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))\\
&=\sum_{i}a^i D_i(f)(\phi(p)).
\end{align}

The third to fourth line is the defintion of the 'partial derivative' notation.

$f$ is ultimately a test function, so I really want to take it out. The last line makes me think I want something like
\begin{align}
\sum_{i}a^i D_i(f)(\phi(p))=\left(\sum_{i}a^i D_i(\phi(p))\right)f,
\end{align}
in which case I can see if I think of $D_i(\phi(p))$ as the standard unit basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then this gives me the vector $a$ as I want.

Is this correct? Is $D_i(\phi(p))$ standard notation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems all ok to me. You may use $\frac \partial {\partial x^i}\big|_{\phi(p)}$ to identify the partial derivatives with respect to the standard coordinates in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: You need to understand how the "vectors as differential operators" concept relates to traditional vectors in $\Bbb R^n$. This concept equates a vector $v \in \Bbb R^n$ with the directional derivative in the direction $v$: $$D_v(f)|_p = \left.\frac{d}{dt}f(p+tv)\right|_{t=0}.$$So the question you need to consider is in $\Bbb R^n$, if $v = \sum_i a_ie_i$, what does $D_v$ look like in terms of $\frac{\partial\phantom{x_i}}{\partial x_i}$?